# Com Add-In not showing up in Com Add-Ins window in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, comaddin

I have generated a DLL of my VB code for my add-in users. This COM Add-In is working on all computers except one.

The user clicks on the COM Add-ins button and then on Add, browses to the correct DLL and clicks OK but the Add-In doesn't appear on the list.

Has anyone else run in to this issue or have a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for Excel 2003:** 
Open Excel Click on Help>About Microsoft Office Excel>Disabled Items Select the Add-In not visible in the Add-Ins window and enable it. Restart Excel and voila!